# Error publishing ECL Content

Tags: ecl

I have installed the YouTube ECL Provider plugin: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/youtube_ecl_provider.aspx

I followed all the steps, copied files, configured XML with folders, etc.. and I managed to load videos of a YouTube account in Tridion. Also, I created a multimedia type for ECL and I have given permission to a Schema to allow this multimedia type: `ExternalContentLibraryStubSchema-folder`.

When I create a new Component with the Schema and I related it with a Video from YouTube provider, the publication crashes with this error:

> Sequence contains no matching element

If I publish the same Component without the video, the publication is success.

How can I publish ECL videos for implement my jspx's?

Comment: Please check the ecl logfile and include the full exception details you find there. It can give a hint on where the error happens.

Comment: The problem has been solved restarting the Service Host service. I don't know why but now it works. Thank you.

Comment: You could add this as an answer and accept it yourself - that way it is easy to find for others that run into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved restarting the Service Host service. I don't know why but now it works.

Thank you.