# Error connecting to ECL

Tags: content-manager, ecl

I constantly get an error on the Test CMS when I try opening components with images.
Attached is the error encountered on opening any component

[image]

There also is the below [image]mentioned error captured in the ECL Log file:

We use CELUM as an ECL provider and SDL Web8.
There are also a few investigations done so far:

1. There have been multiple stub folders created over a period of time although the config file refers just one and each has it's own stub schema as shown below:
   [image]
2. I want to clean up this mess but can someone suggest the correct approach to move forward and get rid of the error encountered?

Comment: Is it not same as https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15276/error-publishing-ecl-content?rq=1 ?

Comment: @NeeleshRaghuvanshi No. I tried restarting the service host but no luck! The error is very much still there.

Comment: Always look in the ecl log file, it often contain additional information that can help troubleshot.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if the image exists in CELUM?

I got the same error when someone deletes the image in the DAM and no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to looks like ECL setup mess up with multiple subfolder Id's.

Try the following steps:

1. Go to this path **[Tridion-Install-Home]\Tridion\config** and open **ExternalContentLibrary.xml**
2. Check the **MountPoint** config section of CELUM ECL provider of **StubFolder** Id, that's the one to be used currently.
3. Removed the unused Folders and old ECL Schemas, while removing if it's not able to delete then it's somewhere used with components, find where used to check those components to remove the ECL item from the field.
4. Try to double check the ECL Connector deployments steps once again to ensure ECL connector works on CMS and you are able to browse those items.
5. Either fix the component in the source tab to remove the ECL item field tag / delete the component and recreate component.
6. Try to add new ECL items to component and test it's working fine or not.

I hope it helps.